# Determine what file a local leafpad instance has open

Tags: ssh, process, forensics

I'm running a leafpad text editor instance on a certain computer, which has a certain file open, whose name and location I have forgotten (it's actually more complicated but this is a simplified version). Then I leave the physical machine, move away, connect to the machine via SSH and get a shell running. I now want to figure out which file that leafpad instance has open.

It's not in leafpad's command-line (checked with `ps`); and its not an open file, or at least - it doesn't seem to show up on `lsof`.

Comment: It's possible that lefpad reads the entire file and keeps its contents in memory. And the name of the file would show up in command line arguments if you ran leafpad like this: `leafpad a.py`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: I didn't start leafpad that way; and - I did try the command-line.

Comment: What do you mean by `I did try the command line`?

Answer (score 0):

You won't file the names of files you opened with `Leafpad` in
`/proc/<PID>/fd` or `/proc/<PID>/maps` because `Leafpad` immediately
closes all files it opens.  You can check that with `strace leafpad`,
for example:

```
open("/home/ja/python/memory-popen/a.py", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 9
lseek(9, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 519
close(9)                                = 0
```

Opened files are reopened and closed again only when saving is done.

As I said in the comment you can pass filename as argument to
`Leafpad` - it would then be recorded in the command name:

```
$ leafpad ~/python/a.py
$ ps aux | grep '[l]eafpad'
ja       12964  1.3  0.2 325764 22328 pts/11   Sl   16:13   0:00 leafpad /home/ja/python/a.py
```

As the last resort you can look for the list of recent files opened by
`Leafpad` in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` but notice that this is not the same as list of files that `Leafpad` keeps open at the moment:

```
$ grep -B 5 -F '<bookmark:application name="Leafpad"' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel | grep -F '<bookmark href='
  <bookmark href="file:///home/ja/python/memory-popen/a.py" added="2019-05-21T13:47:23Z" modified="2019-05-21T14:05:20Z" visited="2019-05-21T13:47:23Z">
  <bookmark href="file:///home/ja/python/motion/motion.py" added="2019-05-21T14:07:21Z" modified="2019-05-21T14:07:21Z" visited="2019-05-21T14:07:21.275528Z">
```

Comment: But I can't strace a process retroactively, can I?

Comment: You can attach to a running process using `strace -p` but you won't see what happened before. But it's not the point - I just mentioned `strace` to show how one could learn what program is really doing.